# Why am I getting an error?

Tags: xcode, ios4, avfoundation

The following line of code compiles with the following warning:

**Code:**

```
[[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error] play];
```

**Warning:**

> /Users/moshe/Development/iPhone/Apps/Live/iDecide/iDecideViewController.m:29:0
>   /Users/moshe/Development/iPhone/Apps/Live/iDecide/iDecideViewController.m:29:
>   warning: multiple methods named
>   '-play' found

What's going on here?

Comment: the error messages tell you to look at line 29 of the iDecideViewController.m file...

Comment: I see the line of code, I've even posted it. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(completely new answer)

The init method is returning type id so you are going to get that message as there are multiple methods with that signature within the Cocoa frameworks

Do it in two steps (init then play) and it should vanish.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
AVAudioPlayer *myplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if(!error) { [myplayer play]; }
```

Comment: I actually copied it from a slide from a WWDC lecture.

Comment: had a think about this. the init method is returning type id so you are going to get that message. 

Do it in two steps (init then play) and it should vanish

Comment: Good call! If you can explain your comment a little better, you get a +1 too!